# Ubuntu 14.04.3 startup slow ('dmesg': "self-detected stall on cpu", maybe because of 'alsa-sink'?)

Tags: boot, alsa, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.03 installed in vmware workstation 12. The bootup to the login takes around 20 secs, after which, the mouse and keyboard becomes unresponsive for 3 to 5 mins.

After managing to type in my password and hitting enter, a dialog pops out (System program problem detected).

[image]

Here is my log:
[dmesg log (pastebin.com)](http://pastebin.com/53y1veah)

Every 100-200 seconds, there are snippets like this:

```
[  126.913012] INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU { 0}  (t=24979 jiffies g=2216 c=2215 q=0)
[  126.913027] Task dump for CPU 0:
[  126.913029] alsa-sink-ES137 R  running task        0  1428   1283 0x00000000
        <shortened...>
[  126.913037] Call Trace:
        <shortened...>
[  126.913127] sched: RT throttling activated
```

PS: I am very new to Linux (5 days), so please be patient with me

Comment: The CPU stall warning detection mechanism seems to be described here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/stallwarn.txt

Comment: This looks as if the 'hardware' emulated by VMWare behaves funny.

Comment: From dmesg the problem is pulseaudio  or alsa (pulseaudio is the audio server on top of Alsa drivers layer ) : try to change the sound card emulated in VMware host config , or disable vm sound for test.

Comment: @laugeo That seems to be the issue. I have disabled the auto detect in sound card, and there is no more 'freezing' at the login. I have tried rebooting multiple times today, issue doesn't popup anymore. Thanks to all for helping to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hardware emulation problem. In my case, I chose to use USB 3.0 that started the problem.

After switching over to USB 2.0, the problem went away.